# Android Sharing data between apps in 2 ways

Tags: java, android

I have app one and app two. In app one I'm sending a string to app two. I want also to return a value from app two to app one. This is my code :

App One:

```
package ed.letslearn.com.appone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SOME_CONSTANT = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                String a="Test";
                b.putString("test",a);
                Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("ed.letslearn.com.apptwo");
                launchIntent.putExtras(b);
                startActivityForResult(launchIntent, SOME_CONSTANT);

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



        switch(requestCode) {
            case (SOME_CONSTANT) : {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                   String thedata = data.getStringExtra("result");
                    Log.d("The data",thedata);
                }
                break;
            }

        }

    }


}
```

App Two:

```
package ed.letslearn.com.apptwo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText thesentvalue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        String text=bundle.getString("test");
        thesentvalue.setText(text);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent goBack = new Intent("ed.letslearn.com.appone");
                goBack.putExtra("result", "Sent from App two");
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, goBack);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }


}
```

I'm not getting the returned string from app two in app one. Any help please ?

Comment: You have mixd up quite a few things

Comment: Yes I know, Can you help please ?

Comment: Please make sure your calling activity not as launch mode single instance in android manifest.xml